# Markup or styling broken on profile page

Tags: bug, design

I'm using Firefox 50.0.2 and noticed the layout in my profile on this site is broken. Something is wrapping or overflowing unexpectedly and it's throwing the whole section off:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Over on Meta.SE: [Badges earned and privileges unlocked in the profile page shows in a weird manner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265866/badges-earned-and-privileges-unlocked-in-the-profile-page-shows-in-a-weird-manne)